# Tring to connect Microsoft Sql server with PHP in MAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp

Im trying to use MS SQL server with PHP in MAMP and I get an error 500.
Below is the php code that Im using.
I learned today that I have to instal a driver but I don't know how to do it in MAMP.:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Any idea? many thanks,

```
<?php
   $serverName = "MPR01\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

   // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
   // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Fund_Lib");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
?>
```

Comment: If you are getting a 500 what do your error logs say?  Also have you displayed errors at the beginning of the php file, to see whats happening?  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: thank you.the php error log says: 
[03-Nov-2017 06:52:16 Etc/GMT-1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\SQL\ejemplo1.php on line 12
and after putting the commands above I get the following message on the screen:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\SQL\ejemplo1.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

With the error message in hand I just found the answer in this post:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55679/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect